# No parallel tests with xUnit DNX

Tags: c#, json, xunit, dnx

I'm trying execute my tests one by one, without parallel.

I tried to configure that on my `xunit.runner.json` file, but without success:

```
{
  "maxParallelThreads": 1,
  "parallelizeAssembly": false,
  "parallelizeTestCollections": false,
  "preEnumerateTheories": false
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are your unit tests' DLLs all placed in the same output folder? If so, then you should change the name of your json config file to `<AssemblyName>.xunit.runner.json`. See [Configuring xUnit.net with JSON](http://xunit.github.io/docs/configuring-with-json.html) for more details. Also, if you're using the console runner, try adding command line option `-parallel none` (it turns off all parallelizations).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm on `dnx 1.0.0-rc1-final`, `xunit 2.1.0`, `xunit.runner.dnx 2.1.0-rc1-build204`, and the `maxParallelThreads` setting in `xunit.runner.json` is working for me from the command line.

Do you have your tests separated by collections? According to [the docs](https://xunit.github.io/docs/running-tests-in-parallel.html):

> By default, each test class is a unique test collection.

So given some contrived "tests" like these, it should be easy to see if they run in parallel or not:

[image]

With:

```
{
    "diagnosticMessages": true,
    "maxParallelThreads":  4
}
```

[image]

With:

```
{
    "diagnosticMessages": true,
    "maxParallelThreads":  1
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For those who are trying to disable parallelism in their .net core (>= 2.1) projects:

Create xunit.runner.json and write below:

```
{
  "parallelizeAssembly": false,
  "parallelizeTestCollections": false
}
```

Add to csproj:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="xunit.runner.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
```

Cheers.